# Best way to build a hierarchical list from path strings

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm

I have a very slow ruby on rails page. It is displaying an hierarchical, unordered list. It was slow, because it was building the list through recursive SQL calls, which was stupid to start with. I've figured out how to get the SQL to give me the hierarchy. Now that I can get the required information through a single SQL call, I'm having issues building the resulting HTML.

This is what my SQL is returning. Each row is a different record, two columns 'id', and 'path'. I can easily break apart the different items by doing `row.path.split` to get something like `['A', 'E', 'F']`. I just can't figure out the best way to manage the opening and closing tags of the list.

```
     ID   |  PATH
01. Root  |  Root
02. A     |  Root A
03. B     |  Root B
04. C     |  Root B C
05. D     |  Root B D
06. E     |  Root A E
07. F     |  Root A E F
08. G     |  Root B D G
09. H     |  Root B C H
10. I     |  Root B D I
11. J     |  Root B D G J
12. F     |  Root B C H F
13. K     |  Root B D I K
14. L     |  Root B D I L
15. F     |  Root B D I L F
```

And I need the unordered list to look something like this:

[image: format of unordered list]

[Source html of the above screenshot](http://pastebin.com/k3dVFGPu)

Comment: Your situation is not clear. I suppose `["A", "E"]` is listed under `["A"]`, with `"A"` omitted. How does that distinguish the cases where `["A"]` exist and cases where it doesn't? In other words, does the existence of `["A", "E", "F"]` entail the existence of `["A", "E"]`, which in turn entails the existence of `["A"]`? If that is the case, then your data is redundant.

Comment: @sawa - The SQL returns every node and it's path. However, in the list,  the nodes are merged, so each node only appears once. `"A"` and `"E"` both appear in the list, but only once. There is no need to have `"A"` be listed as both a node and a leaf

Comment: You didn't seem to get my question correctly. Please read it again. In order to merge `["A", "E"]` with `["A"]`, you need to have `["A"]`. I am asking whether it is the case that whenever you have `["A", "E"]`,  you also have `["A"]`.

Comment: @sawa - yes, the data is a bit redundant. I'm using [Oracle's connect by](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) function to build the paths, that is just how it works. The problem I'm having isn't the data, it is how best to build the `HTML` unordered list with all the opening and closing tags

Comment: @sawa - I updated my SQL to include the ID of the records, maybe that will help explain what is going on.

Comment: I think the SQL part is not crucial for your question. what you really should be asking is, how to convert an array of array into the html format you want. You should either provide the array with redundancy removed, or note that it has the kind of redundancy mentioned above.

Comment: @lightswitch05 Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, if the data is large, I would recommend simplifying the query to return only the rows with leaf data. There are only 5 of these in your sample data, which contains all the information you need.

In either case, this code generates the desired html:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

$h = Hash.new
DATA.each do |path| # replace this line with the SQL query
  hash = $h
  path.split(' ').each do |e|
    if hash.has_key?(e)
      hash = hash[e]
    else
      hash = hash[e] = Hash.new
    end
  end
end

def hash_to_string( h )
  return if h.empty?
  list_items = h.map { |k,v| "<li>#{k}#{hash_to_string(v)}</li>\n" }
  return "\n<ul>\n#{list_items.join}</ul>";
end

puts hash_to_string( $h )

__END__
Root
Root A
Root B
Root B C
Root B D
Root A E
Root A E F
Root B D G
Root B C H
Root B D I
Root B D G J
Root B C H F
Root B D I K
Root B D I L
Root B D I L F
```

I'd suggest running this script first directly as it is, to see that it generates the expected html. Then tweak it to conform to your needs; mainly the `DATA.each ...` line.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive version of Hash building, `DATA` assumed exactly as in @Matt's answer and also the resulting hash will be the same, so `hash_to_string(h)` will work the same.

```
class Hash
  def merge_path path 
    return if path == []
    first, rest = path.first, path[1..-1]
    self[first] ||= {}
    self[first].merge_path rest
  end
end

hash = {}
DATA.lines.map(&:split).each { |path| hash.merge_path path }
```

Generally you should be careful when reopening and extending core and stdlib classes.